# Use shell Command in Spring Batch SystemCommandTasklet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I wanted to run this command in spring batch systemCommandTasklet but it is not working.

```
 tail -1 file1.txt > input_footer.txt && head -n -1 file1.txt > input_body.txt
```

**Code:**

```
        String Commmand = String.format("tail -1 %s > input_footer.txt && head -n -1 %s > input_body.txt", fileName.getFilename(),fileName.getFilename());

        systemCommandTasklet.setCommand(Commmand);

        systemCommandTasklet.setWorkingDirectory(woringDir);
        systemCommandTasklet.setTimeout(10000);
        systemCommandTasklet.setInterruptOnCancel(true);
```

No output files are getting generated.

is there any workaround for this?
Basically I wanted to separate the Body and footer into the two files as a first step.

Comment: I am not sure how this question relates to *java* or *spring*. `head` and `tail` print 10 lines by default and here you specified 1.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using ProcessBuilder and MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter

```
public ExitStatus processFile(String fileName, String workingDir) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
        logger.info("OS windows {} :", isWindows);
        String command = String.format("tail -1 %s > input_footer.txt && head -n -1 %s > input_body.txt", fileName, fileName);
        logger.info("command {} and working dir{} :", command, workingDir);
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();

        builder.command(bashPath, "-c", command);
        builder.directory(new File(workingDir));
        Process process = builder.start();
        StreamGobbler streamGobbler =
                new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        ExitStatus status = exitCode == 0 ? ExitStatus.COMPLETED : ExitStatus.FAILED;

        return status;
    }

 public MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter preProcessFileAdapter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['customerFile']}") String file, PreProcessFile preProcessFile)
    {
        String workingDir = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(file);
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(file);

        MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter methodInvokingTaskletAdapter=new MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter();
        methodInvokingTaskletAdapter.setTargetObject(preProcessFile);
        methodInvokingTaskletAdapter.setTargetMethod("processFile");
        methodInvokingTaskletAdapter.setArguments(new String[]{fileName,workingDir});



 return methodInvokingTaskletAdapter;
    }
```